# Modifying the width of an underline using attributed text?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsattributedstring

Is there a a way to modify the line width of the underline an NSAttributedString?

It seems I can easily modify the color but I can't modify the width of the underline itself easily.

Comment: Just realized - do you mean the width or the thickness of the line? If it's width (like which letters it underlines) then set to a range in an `NSAttributedString`

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: The two solutions before kind of solve the behavior (underline with a specific width) but aren't really solutions to the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can set `NSUnderlineStyleThick` or `NSUnderlineStyleSingle`, eg:

```
NSAttributedString *str = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Thick underline" attributes:@{NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: @(NSUnderlineStyleThick)}];
NSAttributedString *str = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Normal underline" attributes:@{NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: @(NSUnderlineStyleSingle)}];
```

Full list of underline styles here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSUnderlineStyle

Answer (score 1):

// assume Label name as "label"

// underline code

```
CGSize expectedLabelSize = [@"Some text" sizeWithFont:label.font constrainedToSize:label.frame.size lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

UIView *viewForUnderline=[[UIView alloc] init];
viewForUnderline.frame=CGRectMake((label.frame.size.width - expectedLabelSize.width)/2,    expectedLabelSize.height + (label.frame.size.height - expectedLabelSize.height)/2,   expectedLabelSize.width, 1);
viewForUnderline.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
[self.view addSubview:viewForUnderline];
```

or you can use following line of code

```
label.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Some Text" 
                                                     attributes:underlineAttribute];
```